# call C# class from C++CLR

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I want to call `C#` class from `C++CLR`. I have also created the wrapper for the same. Suppose In `C#` class library:

```
namespace MyImage
{
   public class DicomHandler
   {
       public void TestImage(DicomImage dicomImage,int height,int width)
       {
       }
   }
   public class DicomImage
   {
   }
}
```

Then in the `Wrapper`, I have created the object of `DicomHandler` and I need to call the `TestImage(DicomImage dicomImage,int height,int width)`.

Wrapper class library includes,

In IWrapper.h

```
#pragma once
#include<windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace MyImage;

#ifdef MANAGEDWRAPPER_EXPORTS
#define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllimport)
#pragma comment(lib,"F:\\8May\\firebreath-FireBreath-firebreath-1.7.0-0-    gdf8659e\\firebreath\\Wrapper\\Debug\\Wrapper.lib")
#endif

class  IWrapper
{
 public:
static  IWrapper *CreateInstance();
static void Destroy(IWrapper *instance);

virtual DLLAPI void Sethandle(HWND  handle)=0;
virtual DLLAPI  void  TestDicomImage(DicomImage^ _dicomImage,int width,int height)=0;
};

In Wrapper.h,

#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <vcclr.h>
#include "IWrapper.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;
 using namespace System::IO;
 using namespace MyImage;
 using namespace std;
  using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

 class  Wrapper:public IWrapper
 {
 private:

gcroot<DicomHandler^> _dicomHandler;
//gcroot<DicomImageHandler^> _dicomImageHandler;
 public:
     Wrapper(){}

virtual DLLAPI void  SetHandle(HWND  handle);
virtual DLLAPI void  TestDicomImage(DicomImage^ _dicomImage,int winwidth,int winheight);


  };
```

In Wrapper.cpp,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "IWrapper.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <tchar.h>
 #include<vcclr.h>
 #include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
    #include <string>
 using namespace System::Reflection;
  using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
 using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;
 using namespace DicomImage;

   void Wrapper::SetHandle(HWND handle)
  {
_dicomHandler=gcnew DicomHandler;
//_dicomImageHandler=gcnew DicomImageHandler;
_dicomHandler->SetHandle((System::IntPtr)handle);
   }


  IWrapper *IWrapper::CreateInstance()
    {
IWrapper *instance =(IWrapper*)new Wrapper();
return (instance);
     }
    void IWrapper::Destroy(IWrapper *instance)
    {
delete instance;
     }
   void  Wrapper::TestDicomImage(DicomImage^ _dicomImage,int width,int height)
     {

_dicomHandler->TestImage(_dicomImage,width,height);
    }
```

then It raises three Errors like

1)error C3395: 'Wrapper::TestDicomImage' : __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention

2)error C3395: 'IWrapper::TestDicomImage' : __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention

3)error C2259: 'Wrapper' : cannot instantiate abstract class

How to fix these errors?Please provide me the solution for it.

Comment: Add a reference to the C# class library.

Comment: You should cast votes and accept an answer if it's the one you are looking for, that way stack overflow stays clean of 'unanswered' questions.

+1 for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

This SO answer describes how to call a C# class from C++ (This example shows how to pass array of some managed objects) using CLI:

```
public ref class CSharpClassName
{
     //code
}
```

[C++ Interop: How do I call a C# class from native C++, with the twist the class is non-static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883086/c-interop-how-do-i-call-a-c-sharp-class-from-native-c-with-the-twist-the-c)

This website could be very helpful as well:

http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/examples/array1.htm

Or this one (with example):

http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Invoke%20.NET%20Assembly%20from%20Native%20C%2b%2b#CLIWrapper

**Solution 2**

Host CLR

http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Invoke%20.NET%20Assembly%20from%20Native%20C%2b%2b#HostCLR

**Solution 3**

Convert .NET assembly to a COM server, and call it from C++ through .NET-COM interop
http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Invoke%20.NET%20Assembly%20from%20Native%20C%2b%2b#COMInterop

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) is a simple tutorial to call managed code from c++. i have used this before and worked fine for me, hope it fulfills your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your c# dll into your c++/cli project as a reference and then e.g.:

```
DicomHandler^ foo = gcnew DicomHandler();
foo->TestImage(..);
```

I assume you already have

```
using namespace MyImage;
```

Comment: But in the Wrapper,there is the problem for TestImage().How should i invoke that DicomImage class with TestImage()?

Comment: You have more info about the wrapper and the exact problem? You could refine your initial question.