# Converting c# code to C++ native code or for x86 Processor

Tags: c#, c++, x86

How can i make my C# console application able to run without .Net frame work
e.g convert it to native c++ code or to some other method so that it will run without .Net frame work.

Edit:
or how can i compile c# code as a native c++ code

Comment: You read the C# source, translating it into C++. Then you make ***losts*** of tests to make sure the functionality haven't changed. And if the C# code is still being worked on you have to do this for *every little change* in the C# code. The *only* way to automate it is if you manage to write a C# to C++ compiler, which will be anything but trivial.

Comment: i am using web services and soap messages in c# and i dont knw how to do it in c++ that's why i only want to convert it

Comment: C# is not C++. You can't convert it if you don't understand both languages and rewrite it yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883086/c-interop-how-do-i-call-a-c-sharp-class-from-native-c-with-the-twist-the-c this may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using tools because there will be complications and it will be hard to test. However if you want to try there are a lot of tools which you are able to find with a simple google search action. For example [here](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html).